# <!--- RENDER FAILED---> with Recurrence field in calendar list

Tags: recurring-events

I've created newform.aspx in SPD 2007 using custom list forms.

problem:
 - recurrence doesn't work. When entering the newform.aspx and the recurrence box is checked it opens up dynamically and allows form submission, but instead of creating items for all the recurrences it creates just one that has a start and end date on the same day.
 - if you look at the item in the editform.aspx it has all of the pertinent fields except the recurrence field. It displays `<!--- RENDER FAILED--->`

I've created a newform.aspx and deleted all views associated with the list but that hasn't fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Gotta love the nicely ambiguous RENDER FAILED message.  I hit a problem like this a few years back and the only solution I found was to drop the custom list, create it again, create the new forms, ***CLOSE (NOT DELETE!!!)*** the default ListViewWebPart that is on those forms and then add my new custom web part below it.